# mdls returns `(null)`

Tags: terminal, command-line

```
function ls-by-added() {
    # Doesn't work well for files having '(null)' as their DateAdded, which some do.
    mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded -raw -- *(D) | \
        xargs -0 -I {} echo {} | \
        sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | \
        sort --reverse | \
        sed -E "s/^.*\\+0000 //" # removes the timestamps
}
```

It doesn't work for dotfiles:

```
ls-by-added                                                                                      
foo
How Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users_k2opt.pdf
research_report_dc_02_k2opt.pdf
research_report_dc_02.pdf
thebookofshaders_k2opt.pdf
thebookofshaders.pdf
A New Kind of Science
- Books alias
Hein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005)_k2opt.pdf
Hein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005).pdf
geMsearch- Personalized Explorative Music Search.pdf
Lumanote- A Real-Time Interactive Music Composition Assistant.pdf
How Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users.pdf
Computability-and-Logic_k2opt.pdf
Computability-and-Logic.pdf
(null) .rm
(null) .foo
(null) .DS_Store
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried `mdimport .` on the working dir before running the command, but it didn't help.

Comment: You might add that your shell is `zsh` to the initial post.

Comment: @fsb Problem is the same in `bash`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `mdls` for this (instead of `ls -U`)? Anyway, if `md` doesn't have the information all you can do is to add `grep -v '(null)` to the pipeline.

Comment: @nohillside `alias last-created='\ls -AtU|head -n1'`. Not `last-added` :)